# iATS Extension Working, but Throwing Errors

Tags: civicontribute, extension, error, php, iats

iATS 1.5.3 is throwing the following errors (1.5.0 was too) on Civi 4.7.10 running under Drupal 7.50 on CentOS:

- Notice: Undefined index: config_backend in _iats_civicrm_domain_info() (line 202 of /home/ourbase/public_html/wcc/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/iats.php).
- Notice: Undefined index: config_backend in _iats_civicrm_domain_info() (line 202 of /home/ourbase/public_html/wcc/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/iats.php).
- Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://wcc.ourbase.us/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/info.xml): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in iATS_Service_Request::iats_extension_version() (line 728 of /home/ourbase/public_html/wcc/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/CRM/iATS/iATSService.php).
- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in iATS_Service_Request::iats_extension_version() (line 729 of /home/ourbase/public_html/wcc/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/com.iatspayments.civicrm-1.5.3/CRM/iATS/iATSService.php).

Transactions seem to go through, so my focus is on getting these errors to not display. Either by correcting the errors or suppressing the notifications. In regards to the latter, I have error reporting turned off everywhere I'm aware of (php settings in cPanel, civicrm itself)

Answer (score 1):

To suppress notices/warnings on Drupal go here:
/admin/config/development/logging

and hit: none
(you'll want 'none' on any production site);

Would you please open up on issue in our GitHub queue:
https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm

paste in your notices - and also let us know exactly what type of transaction you're executing when these notices occur? Frontend/backend; Credit Card; ACHEFT; SWIPE; one-time/recurring; Contribution; Membership or Event etc.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to that Drupal setting. I feel dumb for missing that. As for the test transactions, I'm actually finding that tests don't get to my iATS reports since going from 1.5.0 to 1.5.3 (contrary to what I said earlier), but I'll refer to the "How to get iATS working" thread for that. Off to github...

Comment: Ok - alternatively feel free to open an issue on GitHub - easier for us to be notified about

Answer (score 0):

Those all look like notices and warnings that are fixed in master.

You do want to suppress warnings and notices on production, but not when you're testing, and the warning above is actually semi-serious. It's trying to set an internal iATS version variable but failing to load it's own file via http.

That's now fixed with this: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/commit/d4f26bc588ced5405d4b6ac4db5a580162926e07

but you should be aware that there might be other issues if your server can't load it's own site via http (e.g. your dashboard might not work).